# Moving data from BigQuery to MongoDB using Google Data Flow?

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a table in BQ and I want to move it to MongoDB using Google Data Flow. I used Data Flow template and created a job.

Once the job is created

1. A VM instance is created to finish the job. The VM instance has an external IP and I whitelisted that external IP on MongoDB. The job ran successfully.

Now I want to schedule this job but everytime the job run on its schedule it creates a new VM with a different external IP and it can't write to MongoDB as the external IP of the VPN is not being whitelisted as a result job failed.

Now the question is how can I run the job on dataflow with a VM instance that runs on a static IP range that I can whitelist in MongoDB and make the pipeline work on schedule.

Dataflow pipeline should work when scheduled from the external IP I had whitelisted in MongoDB.

Comment: Maybe by [reserving an external static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) and adding that IP to the whitelist on Atlas.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You can reserve a static IP and assign it to existing VM or just keep them unassigned. It looks like there is no way to assign the same static IP on the fly when dataflow creates a VM to run a job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reserve an IP on GCP, setup a Cloud NAT on your VPC, run your Dataflow pipeline with private IP on the same VPC you configured your Cloud NAT. The public IP is the one you need to whitelist on MongoDB side.